# How to get the Field Label from the Columns retrieved from the List view Metadata?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, list-view, schema

I have written an Metadata API from https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi to get the List view details.

Below is my code:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetadataServiceExamples.createService();
MetadataService.ListView listView =
(MetadataService.ListView) service.readMetadata('ListView',
new String[] { 'Account.Energy_and_Biotech_Accounts' }).getRecords()[0];
if(listView.columns!=null)
for(String column : listView.columns)
System.debug('Column ' + column);
```

For Annual revenue - the column is displayed as `ACCOUNT.SALES` in system.debug and Shipping street is displayed as `ACCOUNT.ADDRESS2_STREET`.

How do I get the exact file label/API name using the columns in the List view retrieved from Metadata?

Comment: The MDAPI doc states `Field names in the ListView columns don’t always match their API name counterparts.` - I think these are a legacy from way back before I started using SFDC (2008) and perhaps yields insight into why (speculation) it takes so long to get new features like dynamic forms added to standard objects :-)